# HTTPRequestValidationException in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

On click of button i want ckeditor value to be passed to handler.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#createtopic').click(function () {
            var text = $('#editor1').val();
           $.ajax({

                    type: "post",
                    url: "Handler/Topic.ashx",
                    data: "text=" +  text, //data to be passed
                    success: function (msg) {
                    $("#result").html(msg)
                       .fadeIn("fast");
                      )
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
        });
```

**Topic.ashx**

```
         public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
           context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
           context.Response.Write("Hello World");
           String topic_content = context.Request["text"];
           context.Response.Write(topic_content);
         }
```

**Error**

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

text="

```
  <p>aaa</p>
```

").

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET checks for dangerous input (bits of HTML, Javascript) and prevents it by throwing the validation exception.  You can get around this by HTML encoding the txt that you're passing in.  A common way to do this is to use a Javascript function:

```
function encodeHtml(text) {
     encodedHtml = escape(text).replace(/\//g,"%2F")
                   .replace(/\?/g,"%3F")
                   .replace(/=/g,"%3D")
                   .replace(/&/g,"%26")
                   .replace(/@/g,"%40");
     return encodedHtml;
 }
```

And use it when passing the values along in your request:

```
data: "text=" +  encodeHtml(text), //data to be passed
```

In your Topic.ashx's codebehind, use [Server.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke.aspx) to read it back in.

Answer (score 0):

ASP won't accept scripts and html tags in querystrings you need to alter the text and then bring it back again. IMO the best way is JSON:

```
data:{ html: JSON.stringify(text)};
```

You may need the JSON plugin for your browser.

You can get this back in code:

```
var serialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var html = serialiser.Deserialize(context.Request.QueryString["html"], typeof(string)); as string;
```

EDIT:

Having tried this in various situations I would suggest also Encoding and decoding.

```
data:{ html: JSON.stringify(encodeHtml(editor.getData()))};
```

You can get this back with:

```
var html = Server.UrlDecode(serialiser.Deserialize(context.Request.QueryString["html"], typeof(string)));
```

encodeHTML is a fuinction from Shah's suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9654774/1109858